# How to set the Voice Search Language in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am trying to develop a voice recognition app which recognizes and displays selected languages.
I have used the following intent extras:

```
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "zh-CN");
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES, "zh-CN");
```

However, the text displayed is not in the preferred language. It only works when I manually go and change the default language in Settings >> Language and input >> Voice search. Is there a way for me to change the voice search language programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found I managed to get it to work after using the following line instead:

```
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh");
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it is working only for few languages like English (en), Hindi (hi), Japanese (ja) but not working for Kannada (kn), Telugu (te), Malayalam (ml). Could you please let me know if there might be any particular reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ja-JP");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS